In MapKit how would i show users location and draw a polyline to a predetermined lat, lon
EDITED:  I edited my code because it was a mess and confusing, so I am trying again.
My overall goal is to get a users location and then provide directions to a lat/lon on the map.
The code below creates directions between two points but how can I make the starting point the users location?
Also.. I dont seem to be able to get the users location blue dot to appear, even though I am getting their location.
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

@Observable
class NewLocationManager {
    var location: CLLocation? = nil
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    func requestUserAuthorization() async throws {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    
    func startCurrentLocationUpdates() async throws {
        for try await locationUpdate in CLLocationUpdate.liveUpdates() {
            guard let location = locationUpdate.location else { return }

            self.location = location
            print(location)
            print("location: \(location.coordinate.latitude), \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
            let lat = location.coordinate.latitude
            let long = location.coordinate.longitude
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var newlocationManager = NewLocationManager()
    @State private var selectedResult: MKMapItem?
    @State private var route: MKRoute?
    
    private let startingPoint = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: 38.941382,
        longitude: -122.484136
    )
    
    private let destinationCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: 37.94479,
        longitude: -122.50959
    )
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            
            Text("New location manager: \(newlocationManager.location?.description ?? "No Location Provided!")")
        }
        Map(selection: $selectedResult) {
            // Adding the marker for the starting point
            Marker("Start", coordinate: self.startingPoint)
            
            // Show the route if it is available
            if let route {
                MapPolyline(route)
                    .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 5)
                
                
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedResult){
            getDirections()
            
        }
        
        .task {
            try? await newlocationManager.requestUserAuthorization()
            try? await newlocationManager.startCurrentLocationUpdates()
            // remember that nothing will run here until the for try await loop finishes
        }
        .onAppear {
            CLLocationManager().requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            self.selectedResult = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: self.destinationCoordinates))
            
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func getDirections() {
        self.route = nil
        
        // Check if there is a selected result
        guard let selectedResult else { return }
        
        // Create and configure the request
        let request = MKDirections.Request()
        request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: self.startingPoint))
        request.destination = self.selectedResult
        
        // Get the directions based on the request
        Task {
            let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
            let response = try? await directions.calculate()
            route = response?.routes.first
        }
    }
    
}


#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


Read how to ask a question and
show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code.
Show what you get with your code and the given input, and where you ...draw a polyline to the destination. Note, latitude range is -90.0 to 90.0 degrees, not 122.

Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: Minimal code. Some code we can compile and run to reproduce your problem, so we can try to find a solution.

I updated my original post to address your concerns above. I hope that it makes my question clearer?

To ....show users location and draw a polyline to a predetermined lat, lon, try this approach
using @State private var destinationCoordinates..., an additional .onChange(of: newlocationManager.location) and a new getDirections2() to get the
polyline route from the startingPoint to the use current location stored in the
destinationCoordinates.
You will have to adjust the logic/parameters in startCurrentLocationUpdates to update the location only if there is a significant change in user location.
@Observable
class NewLocationManager {
    var location: CLLocation? = nil
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    func requestUserAuthorization() async throws {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    
    func startCurrentLocationUpdates() async throws {
        for try await locationUpdate in CLLocationUpdate.liveUpdates() {
            // adjust the logic/parameters as you require
            let oldLocation = self.location == nil ? CLLocation() : self.location!
            guard let newLocation = locationUpdate.location else { return }
            if !oldLocation.isClose(to: newLocation, withinDistance: 50.0) {
                self.location = newLocation
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var newlocationManager = NewLocationManager()
    @State private var selectedResult: MKMapItem?
    @State private var route: MKRoute?
    
    // for my tests, Tokyo garden
    private let startingPoint = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.661991, longitude: 139.762735)
    
    @State private var destinationCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.67, longitude: 139.763)  // <--- here @State
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(selection: $selectedResult) {
            UserAnnotation()
            // Adding the marker for the starting point
            Marker("Start", coordinate: startingPoint)
            // Show the route if it is available
            if let route {
                MapPolyline(route)
                    .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 5)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: newlocationManager.location) {  // <--- here
            if let coord = newlocationManager.location?.coordinate {
                destinationCoordinates = coord
                getDirections2()
            }
        }
        .task {
            try? await newlocationManager.requestUserAuthorization()
            try? await newlocationManager.startCurrentLocationUpdates()
            // remember that nothing will run here until the for try await loop finishes
        }
        .onAppear {
            CLLocationManager().requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            selectedResult = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationCoordinates))
        }
    }
    
    // --- here
    func getDirections2() {
        route = nil
        // Create and configure the request
        let request = MKDirections.Request()
        request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: startingPoint))
        request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationCoordinates))
        // Get the directions based on the request
        Task {
            let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
            let response = try? await directions.calculate()
            route = response?.routes.first
        }
    }
    
}

extension CLLocation {
    func isClose(to otherLocation: CLLocation, withinDistance distance: CLLocationDistance) -> Bool {
        return self.distance(from: otherLocation) <= distance
    }
}

Note, you also need to enable the appropriate privacy settings/info.plist of your App for location usage.
